# Number of zeroes of a function

Tags: real-analysis

$a_i$,  $i=1,2018$ are distinct real numbers.
Find number of zeroes of a function:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a_1} + \frac{1}{x-a_2} + ... + \frac{1}{x-a_{2018}}$$

Problem is in the limits and continuity section ...

Comment: No idea. What happens for two distinct real numbers? How about three?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** From

$$P(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2018}(x-a_i) \text{ and }
P'(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2018}\prod\limits_{k=1,k\ne i}^{2018}\left(x-a_k\right)$$
then 
$$f(x)=\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x-a_i}$$
and the answer is in $P'(x)$ and [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

---

Another, not as easy as the previous one, **hint** is to use [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) (aka IVT). E.g. let's assume $a_1<a_2<...<a_{2018}$ and let's consider 2 adjacent $a_{i}<a_{i+1}$. It's not too difficult to see that 
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a_i^{+}}f(x)\rightarrow +\infty$$ 
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a_{i+1}^{-}}f(x)\rightarrow -\infty$$
or, there $\exists \varepsilon>0$ s.t. $f(a_i +\varepsilon)>0$ and $f(a_{i+1}-\varepsilon)<0$. Also, $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a_i +\varepsilon, a_{i+1}-\varepsilon]$. By IVT, $f(x)$ has a zero in $[a_i +\varepsilon, a_{i+1}-\varepsilon]$. It remains to show this zero is unique, between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be done without derivatives or using more advanced tools

Comment: Are you familiar with the Rolle's theorem?

Comment: No, I'm not. What is the point of that question ?

Comment: It's a fairly simple theorem. I learned it as part of my high school curriculum, many years ago though ... so I assumed you probably learned it, but (as it happens) forgot it. Never mind ...

Comment: Yes but even if I know it, I'm interested in how to do this just using limits (doesn't make much sense to use limits here) and continuity, because problem is in that section of textbook ..

Comment: Since $P(x)$ has 2018 distinct zeroes, $P'(x)$ must have at least 2017 distinct zeroes (by Rolle's theorem) at points $\ne a_i$. On the other hand, as  $P'(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 2017, by the fundamental theorem of algebra is HAS exactly 2017 roots which can be complex and counted with multiplicity. Taking both statements together, $P'(x)$ has exactly 2017 distinct zeroes at points $\ne a_i$. Since they are not cancelled by the zeroes of the denominator (which are at $a_i$), the zeroes of  $P'(x)$ are the zeroes of $f(x)$ and this is  what you want.

Comment: @someone the way to figure this out with minimal theory is to draw a careful graph for, say, $\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-2},$ on graph paper by hand if you can, but in any case figuring out how to prove that what the picture indicates really does happen for any two real $a_1, a_2.$ Then the same thing for  $\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-2}+ \frac{1}{x-3}.$

Comment: @someone I may have another approach, but I need to know if you are familiar with [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, of course. Apparently, I was not being clear enough about this problem being in continuity section of my textbook.

Comment: I drew a picture, posted. Scale is not the best for seeing the vertical asymptotes.

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

============================================

Comment: yeah, got it now, from your and other answer